# load more javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple categories on my page and a scrollnav js. 
In my html, I have `hidden` the extra options and trying to display them through javascript.

It saw this one in a codepen http://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/sGkvH?editors=0010

it works in the codepen but not in my project. 
this is my html

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-0 side-nav">
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
    <div class="main container">
        <article class="post__article">
            <section class="feature-section row-fluid" id="templates">
                <h2 class="main-feature-heading" id="scrollNav-1">loren ipsum</h2>
                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/import.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/filters3.PNG" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/groups.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/teams.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/campaign.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/permission.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a href="#" id="loadMore"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            </section>
            <section class="feature-section row-fluid" id="manuals">
                <h2 class="main-feature-heading" id="scrollNav-2">loren ipsum</h2>
                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/iphone-android.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                    loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/android-sync.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                    loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/android-groups.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                    loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/iphone-map.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                    loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/iphone-custom-fields.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                   loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/iphone-canvass.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                    loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                       loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </section>
            <a href="#" id="loadMore"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <section class="feature-section row-fluid" id="advertise">
                <h2 class="main-feature-heading" id="scrollNav-3">loren ipsum</h2>
                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/results.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                    loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/map-analytics.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                    loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/customfield-analytics.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                   loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/surveys.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                   loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/canvasser-paths.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                    loren ipsum
                                </h3>
                    <p>
                       loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </section>
            <a href="#" id="loadMore"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-down"></i></a>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is js

```
  $(function () {
    $("#templates-loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#templates >.feature:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
        if ($("#templates >.feature:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
    $("#manuals-loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#manuals >.feature:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
        if ($("#manuals >.feature:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
    $("#advertise-loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#advertise >.feature:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
        if ($("#advertise >.feature:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

I have used `#templates >.feature:hidden` because I have multiple categories and I want to load more options only of the one which the user has clicked.

Comment: `it works in the codepen but not in my project` - any clues in the browser developer tools?

Comment: You maybe missing jQuery? Bcuz you're trying to refer it on your code

Comment: @JaromandaX no errors in dev tools

Comment: @FREEZE nope I am not missing that because if I would, I would had got an error message in dev tools

Comment: can you create a fiddle reproducing the error?

Comment: actually

        '        $("#templates >.feature:hidden").show().slice(0, 2);'
this line of code is not working

Comment: @NaumanTanwir Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some small problems found in your code.

`$("#templates >.feature:hidden").show().slice(0, 2)`

above line is wrong. as per the codepen url you provide it will be

`$("#templates >.feature:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();`

Also Load more button should be at the end.

After that it will be like this.

```js
$(function () {
        $("#templates >.feature").slice(0, 2).show();
        $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#templates >.feature:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
            if ($("#templates >.feature:hidden").length == 0) {
                $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
            }
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 1500);
        });

    });
```

```css
#templates >.feature {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-0 side-nav">
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
    <div class="main container">
        <article class="post__article">
            <section class="feature-section row-fluid" id="templates">
                <h2 class="main-feature-heading" id="scrollNav-1">loren ipsum</h2>
                

                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/import.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsum loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/filters3.PNG" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/groups.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
 
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/teams.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/campaign.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature hide text-center ">
                    <img src="../img/features_screenshots/permission.png" class="feature-screenshot">
                    <h3 class="feature-heading">
                                        loren ipsum
                                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        loren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsumloren ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </section>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tintucraju/zpu547rf/

**Update**

In your update you have assigned click events to

`#templates-loadMore,#manuals-loadMore,#advertise-loadMore`

but it is not there in your html.  so change the id

`<a href="#" id="loadMore"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-down"></i>Load more advertise</a>`

to

`<a href="#" id="templates-loadMore"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-down"></i>Load more advertise</a>`

Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tintucraju/zpu547rf/1/

Also , initially all items are hidden so if you want to show first few records on load then do it like this.

```
  $("#templates >.feature").slice(0, 2).show();
  $("#manuals>.feature").slice(0, 2).show();
  $("#advertise>.feature").slice(0, 2).show();
```

Comment: hi, thanks for responding. I have just edited my question with html and JS. kindly have a look.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer. I doing exactly what you have suggested above. But still, it just 'slides down' and doesn't show anything items. not sure where I am going wrong though. 

I also tried using

'$("#templates >.feature").slice(0, 2).show();
  $("#manuals>.feature").slice(0, 2).show();
  $("#advertise>.feature").slice(0, 2).show();' instead of slideDown() but still no luck.

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle.. is that working as you expected.? is there any error in console.?

Comment: yes, the code is working in the fiddle exactly as I wanted. thats the weird part and yea I checked the console and there are no errors in there

Answer (score 0):

I am almost there.

this is how solved my problem.

```
 $("#templates-loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#templates .feature:hidden").slice(0, 3).toggleClass("hide");
    if ($("#templates .feature:hidden").length == 0) {
        $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:( $(this).offset().top - $(window).height())
    }, 1500);
});
```

now just have to figure out why this is not working.

```
if ($("#templates .feature:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
        }
```

it says `undefined` when I paste it in console.